# Second bounty to Q when funding party has provided an answer: are the conditions cumulative?

Tags: support, bounty

The situation is as follows:

- A bounty is set for 50pts by non-OP
- The funding party contributes an answer
- The bounty is awarded

Then you read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

- To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on
  a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum
  spend is 100 reputation (not 50).
- Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question,
  the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation
  on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third,
  and so on).

If a bounty is set again on the same question, will the cost be 100 or 200? In other words are those somehow cumulative? And does *multiple bounties* refer to them being at the same time in any way i.e. would the result be different here if the second bounty had been started when the first one was still up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the answer is that in the situation described, the restrictions don't add up, and the cost would be `100 points`.